Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refs')
Getting below error when XYZ component called.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'refs')
    at detach (chunk-Y4ZIAFTH.js?v=375eb230:3053:3)
    at chunk-Y4ZIAFTH.js?v=375eb230:3125:9
    at chunk-Y4ZIAFTH.js?v=375eb230:3080:9
    at safelyCallDestroy (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:16748:13)
    at commitHookEffectListUnmount (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:16875:19)
    at commitPassiveUnmountOnFiber (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:18232:17)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_complete (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:18213:15)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects_begin (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:18204:15)
    at commitPassiveUnmountEffects (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:18169:11)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:19489:11)
    at flushPassiveEffects (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:19447:22)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:18868:11)
    at flushSyncCallbacks (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:9119:30)
    at commitRootImpl (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:19432:11)
    at commitRoot (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:19277:13)
    at finishConcurrentRender (chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:18805:15)

chunk-E6XXLY7I.js?v=375eb230:14032 The above error occurred in the <XYZ> component:

I have used the cleanup function in the XZY Component ->   useEffect(() => {
if (!container.current) return;
const handleClickOutside = (e) => {
  if (isSecDropDown && !container.current.contains(e.target)) {
    setIsSecDropDown(false);
  }
};

document.addEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);

return () => {
  document.removeEventListener('mousedown', handleClickOutside);
};

}, [isSecDropDown]);
